# New lines list into array

Tags: ruby, arrays, list

I have a list containing new lines and I like to convert it into an array, e.g.

```
JAN 

FEB 

MAR

APR

MAY
```

into `["JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY]`

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Something like this doesn't seem to work (text_file.txt contains a list of months as above)

```
file = File.new("text_file.txt", "r")
while (line = file.gets)
    line.chomp 
    list = line.split(/\n/)
    puts "#{list}"
end
```

Comment: is list a text file or something? If it is you can read each line of File, strip it and push remaining in your array.

Comment: Please don't ask a new question for each line of an algorithm you are having problems with.  You can [edit] to add more info, and after the required wait you can add a bounty to this question if you haven't gotten a good enough answer (per the [faq#bounty]).

Comment: You never selected an answer. Were none helpful?

Answer (score 22):

This works on 1.9.. not sure if empty? is available in 1.8 though

```
%(
JAN 

FEB 

MAR

APR

MAY
).split(/\n/).reject(&:empty?)
```

Comment: +1 I tested it, working without trouble on 1.8.7; 1.9.3; 2.0.0

Comment: I suggest a small change to the regex to deal with "empty" lines: `/\n\n*/`.

Comment: You can also use `/\n+/`

Answer (score 7):

If you mean this kind of list

```
text = "JAN\nFEB\nMAR\nAPR\nMAY"
```

then you can convert it to array like this

```
text.split(/\n/) => ["JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY"]
```

**UPDATE:**
Second try:

```
text = []
File.read("text_file.txt").each_line do |line|
  text << line.chop
end
puts text => ["JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY"]
```

Comment: Nope, this doesnt seem to work either.  I get back the same list.

Comment: The 'text' variable contains the result, if you want to store result to file, you should write result to file.

Comment: how do you do if I have a line `JAN 01` `FEB 02` I want to store month names and their number in different arrays?

Comment: in other words how to strip the `tab` in each line.

Comment: @Clone by [matching with regular expressions](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html#method-i-match)

Answer (score 4):

I realize this question is several years old, but I had the same question and was unable to create an array with the other answers.

I figured it out by using the following code (note:y list was separated by a return and not a newline):

For data separated by a return:

```
text = []

input = File.read("x_values.txt")
  text = input.split("\r")
puts text.to_s
```

If you want to split on a newline instead:

```
text = []
input = File.read("x_values.txt")
  text = input.split("\n")
puts text.to_s
```

Answer (score 3):

I found [michalfs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8309964/new-lines-list-into-array/32582258#32582258) one-line solution very helpful, though I'd like to note a subtle detail *(which will probably be only interesting to ruby-newbies like myself)*.

If the **Y** of MAY is the last character in the textfile, the resulting array will look like this:

```
["JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MA"]
```

Why so? Quoting from the [String#chop ruby doc](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-chop):

> **chop → new_str** Returns a new String with the last character removed. [...]
>   **String#chomp** is often a safer alternative, as it leaves the string unchanged if it doesn’t end in a record separator.

Therefore `chomp` seems to be more accurate in this particular case:

```
File.readlines("text_file.txt").map{ |l| l.chomp }.reject{ |l| l == '' }
```

(Yes, I only added the *'m'* to michalfs solution.)

Answer (score 0):

Try to get another array and push lines into that with out "\n"
like this

```
 def read
        a=[]
        i=0
            File.open('text_file.txt', 'r') do |f1|  
                while line = f1.gets  
                    line.chomp  
                    ppp= line.split(/\n/)
                    a[i] =ppp[0]
                    i=i+1
                end  
                 puts "#{a}"
            end 
        end
```

Answer (score 0):

One-liner that returns the array of lines, ignoring any empty lines:

```
File.readlines("text_file.txt").map{ |l| l.chop }.reject{ |l| l == '' }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a note. This way, you can also arrange a conversion to array:

```
text = "JAN,FEB,MAR,APR,MAY"

res = text.split(",")

res.each { |x| puts x }
puts res.kind_of?(Array)
```

Response:

```
JAN
FEB
MAR
APR
MAY
true
```